# How to show a View for an existing instance of a ViewModel with MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin.ios, modal-dialog, mvvmcross

I think my question title is pretty clear.
For information I'm using MvvmCross vNext.. I know I should use v3 but I'm still reticent since commits are still made every week on this version... I prefer to wait for a real stable version.

I'm in a case which we use a NetworkViewModel to manage a network representation. It is also responsible to check the connection status to the server. If the connection is down, the ViewModel will post a login message to which my view is subscribed.
When receiving it, I create a dialog (as MonoTouch.Dialog but bound to my ViewModel, so a MvxTouchDialogViewController of my NetworkViewModel) which I show as a modal view (I'm using the MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter). To be able to create my dialog on the same ViewModel, I've applied to it the MvxUnconventionalViewAttribute to prevent it to register 2 View on the same ViewModel type on startup.
Then I use a MvxShowViewModelRequest to create an instance of my MvxTouchDialogViewController and present it with the Show method of my presenter.

My problem is that in this case, a new instance of my NetworkViewModel is created to attach my dialog on. Or I want to reuse the same NetworkViewModel instance for my modal dialog.

The equivalent behavior is possible in Android by using the BindingInflate method on the current NetworkViewModel instance and specifying the login dialog xml layout file.

Is there any equivalent for iOS ?

Thanks,

G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the mvx behaviour so that it doesn't always create a new viewmodel, then you can override the viewmodel locator to provide custom viewmodel lookup for one or more viewmodel types.

See this question/answer for more information - [MvvmCross: Does ShowViewModel always construct new instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723078/mvvmcross-does-showviewmodel-always-construct-new-instances/16723459#16723459)

Comment: Thansk for your answer Stuart, it helped me to understand some part still not clear for me about MvvmCross.