# Creating only one instance of a ViewModel and View

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to open only one instance of a `ViewModel` and it's bound View. However, when I call `base.ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>()` in my `FirstViewModel` it always creates a new `View` and does not update the one I created before.

I tried all `LaunchMode`s for the `Activity` but it does not hit `OnNewIntent()` method in any case.

Comment: What did you change the `LaunchMode` to?

Comment: see this 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723078/mvvmcross-does-showviewmodel-always-construct-new-instances

Comment: For creating singleton ViewModel instance, see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#overriding-viewmodel-locationconstruction . For creating single views, that will require some custom presenter and Android specialness - see the suggestions/hints from the previous comments